# How HttpContext.Current is visible for the whole application if it isn't static?

Tags: c#, .net

I really don't understand how a class like `HttpContext.Current` is visible (for the single request) to the whole web application, without be "static".

Which kind of treatment .NET do for that class?

Comment: It will probably use `CallContext` and/or `ThreadStaticAttribute`, internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In class HttpContext, Current is static property

```
public static HttpContext Current { get; set; }
```

More information see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is what is called a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

Here's [a good explanation of the Singleton pattern with examples in C#](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx)

Comment: He knows that. What he's asking is why the value of the singleton is different for each request. Effectively it is a violation of the singleton pattern.

Comment: @NathanE - *that's* what he's asking? I feel you're formulating your own question here because there's no way to extract what you say from his question.

Comment: His question, although slightly written in pig english, is perfectly clear to me. He specifically mentions being interested in how it works "for the single request".

Comment: Oh well, I'll leave my answer as it is, for that is what I interpret. Hope for him that you are right so you can provide him with a better answer.